# Accuracy of measurement (Calculus 1)

Tags: calculus

Suppose you are living on a straight line. There are several satellites at height $20, 000$ kilometers and you get readings saying that satellite 1 is directly above the point $x_1 ± 10^{−10}$ and is at a distance $h_1 = 21, 000 ± 10^{−2}$ from you, satellite 2 is directly above $x_2 ± 10^{−10}$ and at a distance $h_2 = 52, 000 ± 10^{−2}$. Where are you ($x_0$) and to what accuracy? Hint: Consider separately the cases $x_1 < x_2$ and $x_2 > x_1$.

My results:

Actually we have two equations:
$$(x_1 - x_0)^2 + (2\cdot10^4)^2 = h_1^2$$
$$(x_2 - x_0)^2 + (2\cdot10^4)^2 = h_2^2$$

We can express $x_0$ from them as:
$$x_0 = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2} + \frac{(h_1 - h_2)(h_1 + h_2)}{2(x_2 - x_1)}$$

But how to compute accuracy of measurement? I'm troubling with $x_2 - x_1$ in denominator.

Comment: I suppose you meant $(2\cdot 10^4)^2$.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Yes, that was a typo, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression for $x_0$ is incorrect. Subtracting the first equation from the second (which also needs to be amended, as given in my comment), we obtain:
$$(x_2-x_1)(x_2+x_+-2x_0)=h_2^2-h_1^2$$
Which means:
$$x_0=\frac {x_1+x_2}{2}-\frac {h_2^2-h_1^2}{2(x_2-x_1)}$$
Note that errors in measurement are much smaller than the measurements themselves. Thus, taking a differential, which can be approximated as the error, we get:
$$dx_0=\frac {dx_1+dx_2}{2}- \left(\frac {(x_2-x_1)(2 h_2 dh_2-2 h_1 dh_1)-(h_2^2-h_1^2)(dx_2-dx_1)}{2(x_2-x_1)^2}\right)$$
Here, $dx_1=10^{-10}=dx_2$ and $dh_2=10^{-2}=dh_1$.

The second differential is merely a consequence of $d(\frac vu)=\frac {vdu-udv}{u^2}$.

Hence error in $x_0$, as well as $x_0$ itself, is calculated.

Comment: Thank you for your solution!

Comment: You're welcome. You could accept the solution if it solves your query satisfactorily.